# How could I go about getting historic records from an IObservable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm monitoring a stream of stock quotes via an Observable which I watch to match a certain condition, e.g -

```
Observable
.Empty<Quote>
.Where(q => q.Price > watchPrice)
.Subscribe(q => { // do stuff } );
```

Now, at the point of "do stuff", what I'd ideally like is to get the last 3 "q"s that come out the where clause, so sort of like BufferWithCount(), but each entry to Subscribe() contains the last 3 entries. This is so I can save a snapshot of the quote changes that led to the condition evaluating.

Pseudo Marble Diagram -

```
in  -  a     b     c     d     e     f
out -  a     ba    cba   dcb   edc   fde
```

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
    static void Main()
    {
        new[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
            .ToObservable()
            .Scan(Enumerable.Empty<string>(), (x, y) => x.StartWith(y).Take(3))
            .Subscribe(x =>
                           {
                               x.Run(Console.Write);
                               Console.WriteLine();
                           });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Legendary. Works a charm! Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow has an issue where a quick, concise, and correct answer that fully gets it right without controversy gets less upvotes than a question with a lot of BS answers and one mostly-right answer. I think this is terrible and I'm going to start correcting it by upvoting your answer. My upvote will obviously create an avalanche of upvotes. You are about to bathe in reputation, sir. Prepare yourself.

Comment: I get the following error: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'StartWith' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Observable.StartWith<TSource>(System.IObservable<TSource>, params TSource[])' has some invalid arguments